# Javascript comments on same line as code: yes or no?

Tags: javascript, comments

So here's some code I've written in Javascript:

```
var panRate = 120; //Max speed of the camera
var panAccelerate = 0.01; //Amount speed increases each frame
var panDecelerate = 1.05; //Amount speed is divided by each frame
```

Is that kosher, putting the comments on the same line as the code? Firefox and Chrome don't seem to be having any problems with it, but does that have the potential to break certain browsers?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that it would break?

Comment: certainly comments in javascript should not break in any browser no matter how they are fomatted.

Comment: the interpreter ignore the comments, you dont need to worry about it

Comment: yes, that's good, no it woudn't break anything

Comment: I could understand the question with the context of ecmascript minifiers etc.

Comment: @jAndy: The minifier that couldn't handle inline comments is the minifier you would have never heard of since no one would use it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for putting up with my stupid question. The reason I ask is because I recall inline comments breaking my code a while back. I think it was because I was using them within an object, though, now that I think about it.

Comment: @Zacqary: Doesn't matter, this is perfectly valid for instance: http://pastie.org/6032355

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript has 2 types of comments, and both work in all browsers.

- `// comment` denotes an "inline" comment. Any characters on that line after the `//` are a comment.
- `/* comment */` are "block" comments. Any characters withing the `/*` and `*/` are a comment, and can span multiple lines.

Both are valid in all javascript implementations, universally.

*Style* is the only real concern here.  And that is a *far* more subjective question.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but does that have the potential to break certain browsers?

No, not any browser that's *remotely* compliant with the ECMAScript specification. No browser I've ever seen has any problem with them. This is **incredibly** basic, if a browser has an issue with this, it will have bigger issues for you to worry about. So don't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your fine, the commented out code begins after the backslashes and ends at the end of the line.